# Do I pass copies of arguments or the arguments themselves to functions within __init__?

Tags: python, arguments

I would like to know which one of the following two alternatives is better, or maybe more Pythonic:

1. Use `__init__` arguments directly as arguments of functions called within `__init__`:

   ```
   def class A(object):
       def __init__(self, x):
           self.x = x # I would like to do this anyway
           self.y = foo(x)
           # More code
   ```
2. Use `__init__` attributes that are copies of arguments as arguments of functions called within `__init__`:

   ```
   def class B(object):
       def __init__(self, x):
           self.x = x # I would like to do this anyway
           self.y = foo(self.x)
           # More code
   ```

The classes A and B should behave identically. However:

1. The first alternative is less verbose since a lot of `self.` typing is avoided and the code is more readable.
2. The second alternative may be more robust to further changes in the code.

Which one of A or B is better? Or perhaps it does not matter?

Comment: There is no copying going on here. `x` and `self.x` are *the same object*.

Comment: @DanielRoseman - You are correct. Still, I may change a later version of my code so that x and self.x become different. In that case version B may still work and version A may break. So there is a trade-off between verbosity (I hope this word exists) and fragility.

Comment: Why not make `y` a property? Then `@property` `def y(self): return foo(self.x)`. This way it's clear what the relationship is and `y` updates as `x` does.

Comment: This is true if y is a function only of x as in the examples. If y is also a function of other variables I may want to delay its recalculation until its other arguments were also set or updated. This is especially the case if y's recalculation is expensive.

Comment: In that case you can memoize the result against the inputs, e.g. in a dictionary `{(x, ...): y}`. That can be implemented as part of the descriptor *or* within the function that's decorated. The nice thing about properties is that you don't have to worry about that until it turns out you need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It matters very little. Not having to type out `self` is nice, and Python won't have to do an attribute lookup.

However, if `self.x` is a *property* that in some way transforms the value when setting or getting, then you have no choice, depending on wether or not you need to use the original `x` or the transformed `self.x`.

Comment: True, but look at my comment on jonrsharpe.

Comment: @Soldalma: I'm not talking about converting `self.y = foo(x)` into a property here. I'm talking about `self.x` already being a property for whatever reason.